# Two point masses don't need gravitational force in their gravitational attraction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

The magnitude of the gravitational acceleration $g$ at which the falling mass is accelerated towards the center of the gravitating mass can be found if we know the mass and radius of the gravitating mass in the equation of $g=GM/R^2$ formulated by Newton. It doesn't even depend upon

1. The magnitude of the gravitational force that exists between the falling mass and gravitating mass.
2. The mass of the falling object, which is accelerated by the gravitating mass towards its center.

It is the gravitational ability of any point mass to accelerate all other objects at the rate of $g=GM/(R+H)^2$ towards its center either in free fall or on its surface, therefore what is the role of the gravitational force $F$ suggested by newton then when each object has the innate power to accelerate all other objects towards its center w/o any force $F$?

When there is a force there is mass but the gravitating mass which has $g=GM/(R+H)^2$, is independent of the mass of the falling object though we can't ignore the center of gravity of falling mass and after all, it is the mass which is falling or accelerated.

if the said object is earth then g= 9.8 m/s/s, R = Radius of earth, and H = Height above the surface of the earth.

**Addendum:** For simplicity, Let A and B are two objects of masses M1 and M2 respectively.
The radius of M1 = R1, The radius of M2 = R2, H1 = Height above A, H2 = Height above B

The gravitational acceleration of A = g(a)= GM1/(R1+H1)^2

All objects including B fall at the same rate g(a) on A.

The gravitational acceleration of B = g(b)= GM2/(R2+H2)^2

All objects including A fall at the same rate g(b) on B.

B attracts A with g(b)= GM2/(R2+H2)^2 or A falls on B @ rate of g(b)= GM2/(R2+H2)^2

A attracts B with g(a)= GM1/(R1+H1)^2 or B falls on A @ the are of g(a)= GM1/(R1+H1)^2

Have you seen any involvement of the force in the falling of A on B or vice versa - Anyone, please? I hope I have explained things clearly enough to understand.

**COMMENT SECTION DOESN'T HAVE ENOUGH SPACE THEREFORE I WRITE MY REPLY HERE:** All above is within the scope of Newtonian physics but unbeknownst to newton and Illuminati.

The ingredients of the equation of the acceleration due to the gravity [g=GM/(R+H)^2] of any spherical object clue in that "g" is brought into existence by the following, not FORCE.

1- G = Gravitational constant.

2- M = Mass of gravitating object

3- (R+H) = Distance

No gravitational force is seen in the eq of g=GM/(R+H)^2

Thinking of [g=GM/(R+H)^2] alone from the original gravitational equation of F=GMm/d^2 means we not only separate gravitational force "F" from "g" but also "G" from the gravitational force "F" however "G" even doesn't depend upon the gravitational force "F" as the unit of force (N=Kg.m/Sec) can't be seen in the unit of G (m^3/Kg.Sec^2). G requires neither falling mass nor the existence of gravitational "F"

Equation of F = GMm/d^2  or G = F.d^2/Mm shows that G depends upon both masses (gravitating and falling) and the gravitational force "F"

Equation of g = GM/d^2 or G = g.d^2/M shows that G depends upon gravitating mass (one mass) but no gravitational force "F"

Comment: "therefore what is the role of the gravitational force F suggested by newton then when each object has the innate power to accelerate all other objects towards its center w/o any force F?" ?????????

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian physics, *mass* has a dual role: gravitational and inertial. According to Newton's law of gravitation, two spherically symmetric mass distributions with centres separated by distance $r$ attract each other with a force of magnitude
$$F=G \frac {Mm}{r^2}$$
in which $m$ and $M$, are the masses. Here mass is playing its gravitational role.

Now if the only force acting on $m$ is the gravitational one from $M$, the acceleration of $m$ will be of magnitude
$$a=\frac Fm.$$
Here $m$ is playing its inertial role.

$$\text{So}\ \ \ \ \ \ ma=G \frac {Mm}{r^2},\ \ \ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ a=G \frac {M}{r^2}.$$
So we see that the acceleration does not depend on the mass of the falling body (your point 2.), because $m$ in its gravitational role cancels with $m$ in its inertial role.

Your point 1. is harder to interpret. The acceleration *does* depend on the magnitude of the gravitational force in that a greater gravitational force will give a greater acceleration. The magnitude of the force itself doesn't appear in the acceleration equation because of the cancellation of $m$. Perhaps you consider that the absence of force in the 'final' equation for gravitational acceleration points to there being no fundamental place for a gravitational force in a theory of gravity. If so you are in good company – but outside the realm of Newtonian Physics!

Comment: I did say there is no involvement of the force in the falling of A on B or vice versa. As g = GM/R^2 therefore the reduction in “g” is due to the reduction in gravitating mass, not FORCE. Acceleration due to gravity depends upon the mass of gravitating mass and its radius.

Comment: In the Newtonian scheme  controls  because  controls 
and  controls . Are you arguing against this, my summary of the Newtonian approach, or are you thinking outside the Newtonian box?

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational force, F, on a mass m due to another mass M is given by $GmM/R^2$. Since F=ma, the acceleration is independent of the mass m as you state in #2 in your question. As for #1, the acceleration does depend on the magnitude of the gravitational force. If M is smaller, there is less force and less acceleration $GM/R^2$. Objects on the moon fall with less acceleration than on the earth because the force of gravity there is less than it is on the earth.

Comment: As g = GM/R^2 therefore the reduction in “g” is due to the reduction in gravitating mass, not FORCE. Acceleration due to gravity depends upon the mass of gravitating mass and its radius.

Comment: But what you call gravitating mass is what determines the force, in addition to distance. g=F/m so for a given m the larger the force the larger the acceleration. Yes, the m's cancel and g only depends on M and R but those are the quantities that determine the force.

Answer (score -1):

**Hey first of all there is no term like gravitating mass**. Now if you mean that there is a body that is pulling a body towards itself then for this Newton gave a universal law of gravitation that states any two bodies attract with a force of

$$G (\frac{Mm}{r^2})$$

**Now using this law, physicists defined gravitational field strength. Now the gravitational field strength should be a property of the body that is exerting force on the other body. So this quantity should be mere property of the object.**

and coincidently it is same as that of the accleration of the attracted body.

> When there is a force there is mass but the gravitating mass which has g=GM/(R+H)2, is independent of the mass of the falling object though we can't ignore the center of gravity of falling mass and after all, it is the mass which is falling or accelerated.

...................................................................................................................................................................................

> For this statement i think that you want to say that for an apple falling on earth why does only apple falls towards the ground why not the earth towards the apple.
> So earth is also displaced towards the apple but the displacement is unobservable because

**1. You are in the frame of earth**

2. Earth is attracted not only by the apple but also by other heavy bodies.
3. It is a minute displacement of about nanometers as **gravitational force is a weak force**

and **one suggestion**
*Please use a simple language it took a lot of understanding and time to firstly interpret your question.*
**On stackexchange we have brains from all over the world who just know enough english to interact with others.**